# How to create dataset from geotiff located in RAM by GDAL

Tags: c++, gdal

Gdal function for open files use filename to read data like so:

```
GDALOpen (const char *pszFilename, GDALAccess eAccess)
```

but my file located in memory. I use next code to create pointer to file:

```
FILE *stream;
stream = fmemopen(buf, lengthOfArray, "r");
```

Is it possible to create GDALDataset by pointer to file somehow?

Any tricks and tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the full example of C++ for processing geotiff file from java bytearray using jni on linux:

```
#include <jni.h>

#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "cpl_string.h"
#include "cpl_conv.h"
#include "gdalwarper.h"
#include "cpl_vsi.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_box_processing_GEOTransform_run(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray array) {
    GDALAllRegister();
    jboolean isCopy;
    jbyte* buf = env->GetByteArrayElements(array, &isCopy);
    jsize lengthOfArray = env->GetArrayLength(array);

    const char *pszFormat = "GTiff";
    GDALDriver *poDriver;
    poDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(pszFormat);

    VSILFILE* fpMem = VSIFileFromMemBuffer ("/vsimem/temp.tif", (GByte*) buf, (vsi_l_offset) lengthOfArray, FALSE );
    VSIFCloseL(fpMem);

    GDALDataset *poSrcDS = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen( "/vsimem/temp.tif", GA_ReadOnly );
    GDALDataset *poDstDS;

    const char *pszSrcWKT = NULL;
    pszSrcWKT=GDALGetProjectionRef(poSrcDS);
    double error_threshold = 0.125;
    GDALResampleAlg resampling = GRA_Cubic;

    char*  pszDstWKT = NULL;
    GDALDataset * tmpDS = (GDALDataset*)(GDALDataset*)GDALAutoCreateWarpedVRT(poSrcDS, pszSrcWKT, pszDstWKT, resampling, error_threshold, NULL);
    poDstDS = poDriver->CreateCopy( "/some/folder/example1.tif", (GDALDataset*)tmpDS, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL );

    GDALClose( (GDALDatasetH) poDstDS );
    GDALClose( (GDALDatasetH) poSrcDS );
    VSIUnlink( "/vsimem/temp.tif" );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

GDAL has the option to create an in-memory file from a buffer. See:

http://gdal.org/cpl__vsi_8h.html#a86b6b1c37bb19d954ee3c4a7e910120c

I dont have experience with C++, but in Python it looks like:

```
with open('myfile.tif', mode='rb') as f:
    gdal.FileFromMemBuffer('/vsimem/some_memfile', f.read())
```

You can then open that virtual location as if its a normal file:

```
ds = gdal.Open('/vsimem/some_memfile')
```

And when you're done with the file, make sure you unlink it, or it will stick around.

```
ds = None
gdal.Unlink('/vsimem/some_memfile')
```

Comment: i know how to make it in python, i just asked for c++, but i'll find answer, thanks